# library routine called out of sequence

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am trying to write into a DB in sqlite on the iphone , i want to enter 3 values into the DB . Given Below is my code but i am getting the following sqlite error message:

```
-(void) writeintoDatabase:(id)value1:(id)value2:(id)value3 {
sqlite3 *database;


    const char *sql = "insert into UserData(firstName,lastName,userName) Values(?, ?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL);

    sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 1, [value1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [value1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 3, [value1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    NSInteger keyID;
printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) ); 

        keyID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);


    sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);

}
```

Comment: you forgot to paste the error message

Comment: Hi Mat,  This was the error message: 'library routine called out of sequence'

Comment: you say in a comment that you managed to solve that error message. if that's the case, update your question with the new code. (and see my answer too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks mmcomb, Thanks Mat. From both your advices i have solved the problem completely.

- **Firstly** I wasn't checking the DB path and then opening the
  connection.
- **Secondly** after having prepared the statement and bounding the
  appropriate variables i had to call `sqlite3_step` before calling
  `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`.
- **Thirdly** i needed to call `sqlite3_finalize` to free the resources.
- **Fourthly** i needed to `sqlite3_close` the connection.

'library routine called out of sequence' error was due to not opening and closing the connection properly.

This is the right code:

```
NSInteger keyID; // in .h class
NSMutableArray *user;// in .h class

-(void) writeintoUserDatabase:(NSString*)value1:(NSString*)value2:(NSString*)value3 
{
sqlite3* database;
databaseName = @"UserData";// create a db with this name and keep it in app resources folder
NSString *pathToDatabase;
NSArray *documentPaths =         NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
pathToDatabase = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
int databaseReturnCode = sqlite3_open([pathToDatabase UTF8String], &database);
NSLog(@"databaseReturnCode %d",databaseReturnCode);
if(databaseReturnCode == SQLITE_OK) {

const char *sql = "insert into UserData(firstName,lastName,userName) Values(?, ?, ?)";
sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL);

    sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 1, [value0 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [value1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 3, [value2 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

printf( "is there an error?: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) ); 

    while(sqlite3_step(insert_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
        NSString *aFirstName  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:      (char*)sqlite3_column_text(insert_statement, 1)];
        NSString *aLastName  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(insert_statement, 2)];
        NSString *aUserName  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(insert_statement, 3)];
users = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:aFirstName,aLastName,aUserName,nil];
    }

keyID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);


    sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);

sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing a call to the `sqlite3_step`. You need to call that after having prepared the statement and bound the appropriate variables, and before you call `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`.

Check the documentation for [`sqlite3_step`](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_step) for details, and **always** check the error codes returned by this type of function.

Don't call `sqlite3_errormsg` if no error has occurred, its result is undefined in that case.

Finally, you need to call `sqlite3_finalize` on the statement if you're not keeping a handle to it somewhere. Otherwise you'll get resource leaks and eventually crash. `sqlite3_reset` does not free the resources, it just "cleans" the statement so you can re-run it with different bound values.

Comment: Thanks Mat, now by means of 'sqlite3_step' i am able to 'commit my updates' as such i.e. i am able to find that what i have added remains!

Answer (score 1):

Before preparing your sqlite stament/query you need to open the connection to your database...

```
sqlite3* database;
NSString pathToDatabase = @"/blah/blah/database.db";
const char* pathToDatabaseUTF8 = [databasePath UTF8String];
databaseReturnCode = sqlite3_open(pathToDatabaseUTF8, &database);
```

See the sqlite documentation for the [sqlite3_open](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) method for more info.

Oh, and don't forget to close that connection...

```
int sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Thanks mmcomb the 'library routine called out of sequence' was solved

Comment: but the data i add does get saved , i mean when i get the db displayed the next time i can't see the additions! Now I have done exactly the same thing though ..

Comment: in other words i am not able to see the updates; how do i commit the updates?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a the string contained some special characters like it was ( ' ) single colon i replaced it with (" ") a space and it start working. [[[items objectAtIndex:locBtn.tag]valueForKey:@"description"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""]